# Show only current branch in Mercurial Eclipse history view

Tags: eclipse, mercurialeclipse

When I switch to an old branch in Mercurial Eclipse, and then view the history by right-clicking on the project in Package Explorer and using Team->Show History, it shows the latest revisions in the whole repository at the top, and the latest revision in the old branch must be somewhere way, way below that. How can I make Mercurial Eclipse show only the revisions in the current branch - or at least jump to the current revision in the list?

I'm using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 on Linux.

Also, I'm not sure but I'm not sure this problem occurs consistently. I think sometimes it works. I also see no graph this time, but sometimes I do see a revision graph, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

To search for a revision you can use the 'Go To' panel.  To enable it press the fourth from the right button in the history view. The 'Go To' panel supports content assist. Note it has performance problems for large histories.

The graph is shown only for file history and repository history. Not for folder history.